# Counting sequences with certain elements fixed

Tags: combinatorics

> You flip a coin $20$ times and record the ordered sequence of heads and tails. How many sequences are there in which you get heads on (at least) flip #$1$, #$4$, #$7$, and #$13$?

Looks like we are being asked to count the number of sequences that look like $htthtthttttthttttttt$ where $h$ stands for heads and $t$ stands for tails. So, then each element of the sequence above would be chosen out of $\{h, t\}$ meaning there are $2^{20}$ such sequences.

I am not sure where I am going wrong here.

Btw, I am sorry if the title doesn't have anything to do with the question. That's not intentional.

Comment: Notice that there is a bijection between the scenario "flip the 20 coins and record them in the order they occurred" and the scenario "flip 20 coins, record the first four flips in slots 1,4,7,13 and the remaining flips in the remaining slots"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The positions 1, 4, 7 and 13 are fixed and you don't count it as times 2 possibilities. There are 16 positions which may vary, so the answer should be $2^{16}$.

Comment: How many sequences defined as those in the OP have the same number of heads and tails? I'd be tempted to say $2^{10}$, but that'd be wrong. Why, though? Aren't we fixing $10$ elements this time?

Comment: Those are counted differently. Since there need to be 10 heads and 10 tails exactly, it is enough to consider how many choices you have for the positions where the heads will be. The answer is $\binom{20}{10}$.